# Listview.setAdapter... crash when I come back from another tab

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a Activity with 3 tabs, inside first a fragment with listview. The listview has custom adapter. There is not problem when I start and when i go to second tab and come back. But when I go to 3th tab and come back to first one, the fragment execute onCreateView and crash with nullpointerexception, this is my code:

The fragment:

```
List<Post> rings;
View headerView;


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_within_ring, container, false);
    headerView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header_list_view, null);

    new consultarRing().execute(); //This get the Array from web service to rings 

    return rootView;
}

private void fullyAdapter() {

    if (rings != null) {

        adapter = new PostsAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_row_show_ring, rings, false, null);

        lyt = (PullAndLoadListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView_withinring);

        lyt.addHeaderView(headerView); //crash here
        lyt.setAdapter(adapter); //crash here


        //crash all down
        lyt.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
            //OnRefreshListener

            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new PullToRefreshDataTask().execute();
            }
        });
        lyt.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new LoadMoreDataTask().execute();
            }
        });
        lyt.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                 int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                switch (firstVisibleItem) {
                    case 1:
                        Main.isScrolling = false;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Main.isScrolling = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

private class consultarRing extends AsyncTask<String, String, CollectionResponsePost> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //do staff
    }

    @Override
    protected CollectionResponsePost doInBackground(String... args) {
        //do staff, get rings
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(CollectionResponsePost responsePost) {

        //call fullyAdapter() method
        fullyAdapter();
    }
}
```

My problem is when the listview tray setAdapter for second time, I dont know how reset listview for start like new. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You execute your AsyncTask inside of `onCreateView`. At that moment the fragment's view hierarchy is not yet added to the activity's, therefore `getActivity().findViewById()` will return `null` if you search for fragment's views.

Try starting the AsyncTask later:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    new consultarRing().execute();
}
```